# When is an NSPersistentDocument's data store moved to final save location?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Following the advice in the Core Data Programming Guide's Core Data Performance [page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5)
regarding storage of BLOBs, I've chosen to store binary data for my
**`NSPersistenDocument-based`** app (Leopard-only, if that makes a
difference) in an external file (separate from the document Core Data
data store) and keeping an archived **`NDAlias`** reference to that file in
my document's data store.

Ultimately, I would like the external data
file to end up in the same directory as the document (data store)
file. Since I may need to write data to the external data file before
the document is saved (this is a scientific data acquisition app and
losing data due to a crash is to be avoided if possible), I've taken
the following approach:

I would like to encapsulate the management of this external file in
the model-related classes since I will need the same functionality
during schema migration. Thus managing the external data file in my
**`NSPersistentDocument's`** subclass seems wrong.

In the object
model's root object, I create the external file in
**`NSTemporaryDirectory()`** in the root objects **`awakeFromInsert`** method and store the **`NDAlias`** referencing the data file.

I would then like to move the external data file to the same directory as the saved data store, when a save occurs.

I thought **`didSave`** would be the appropriate place
to do it, but it looks like during invocation of the **`didSave`** method,
the persistent store is still in a temporary directory (presumably
before being **`FSExchangeObjects'd`** to create an atomic save operation).

I plan to factor the logic in **`awakeFromInsert`** and **`didSave`** into class
methods so that they can be called during schema migration in a custom
entity policy's
`createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:
and endInstanceCreationForEntityMapping:manager:error:` respectively.

So, my question: when during a **`NSPersistentDocument`** save can I be assured that my root object's **`objectID.persistentStore.URL`** is the 'final' URL of the save (e.g. where the user chose to save the file for document save)?